# Display the sum of digits in a number entered by the user

Tags: c#

I need to get a number from the user and display the sum of that number's digits. For example, the sum of the digits in the number `12329` is `17`.

Here's what I tried to do and it is giving me the ASCII code instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter a number: ");
string num = Console.ReadLine();
int len = num.Length;
int[] nums = new int[len];
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
while (count < len)
{
    nums[count] = Convert.ToInt32(num[count]);
    count++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    sum += nums[i];

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: What you are programming in is not #C or C, but C#.

Comment: I always prefer your solution to the problem.  It is much faster than other methods.   The other method is to use module 10 to remove one digit at a time and then divide by 10 to get next digit.  The module 10 solution you have to convert the string to a number which is stored as a binary number.  Then you are actually taking the binary number and dividing by 10 and you can get a fraction which rounds incorrectly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. All in all the people here expect a little more research before posting a question. Or at least showing that your research has led you nowhere. But actually for you first question this is not a bad post. Has the entire code to reproduce the problem and a clear problem description with examplary input and expected output. Keep on this track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake. `char` is really just a number - the encoding value of the character represented by the `char`. When you do `Convert.ToInt32` on it, it sees the `char` as a number and says "alright let's just convert this number to 32 bits and return!" instead of trying to parse the character.

"Wait, where have I used a `char` in my code?" you might ask. Well, here:

```
Convert.ToInt32(num[count]) // 'num[count]' evaluates to 'char'
```

To fix this, you need to convert the `char` to a `string`:

```
nums[count] = Convert.ToInt32(num[count].ToString());
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now you are calling a different overload of the `ToInt32` method, which actually tries to parse the string.

Comment: thank you..... I was already getting crazy ;) because no one even intended to describe the cause of the problem. have an upvote for preserving my sanity

Comment: oh I would have accepted it a long time ago, but I did not post the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you access your string with a index (in your case `num[count]`) you get a char type and because of that you are getting ASCII values. You can convert char to string with `.ToString()` in your case `nums[count] = Convert.ToInt32(num[count].ToString());`.I posted here another approach to your problem:

```
string number = Console.ReadLine();
int sum = 0;
foreach (var item in number)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: There's no point in creating that char array you can just `foreach` over the chars in the string `foreach(var item in number)`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would work with a foreach loop without converting the string to a char array. I corrected it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed the `Convert.ToInt32(num[count])` will only return the Unicode code of the `char` you want to convert, because when you use the `[]` operator on a `string`, you will get *readonly access to [the] individual characters of a string* [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string).

And so you are using [`Convert.ToInt32(Char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx), which

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

One way to cast the numeric value from a `char` to a digit, is using [`Char.GetNumericValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which

> Converts a specified numeric Unicode character to a double-precision floating-point number.

---

By `using System.Linq;` you can cut your code to just a few lines of code.

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter a number: ");
string num = Console.ReadLine(); // "12329"

int sum = (int)num.Select(n => Char.GetNumericValue(n)).Sum();

Console.WriteLine(sum); // 17
```

---

*What does this line of code?*

The `num.Select(n => Char.GetNumericValue(n))` will iterate over each char in your string, like your `while` and converts each value to a `double` value and return an `IEnumerable<double>`. The `Sum()` itself will iterate over each value of the `IEnumerable<double>` and calculate the sum as a `double`. And since you want an integer as result the `(int)` casts the `double` into an integer value.

---

*Side-Note:*

You could check your input, if it is really an integer. 
For example:

```
int intValue;
if(Int32.TryParse(num, out intValue))
{
     // run the linq
}
else
{
     // re-prompt, exit, ...
}
```

If you are using `Char.GetNumericValue()` on an letter it will return `-1` so for example the sum of `string num = "123a29";` will be `16`.